# showing non-isomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> How do I prove that there is no isomorphism between $\Bbb Z$ under addition and $\Bbb Q$ under addition?

They both are infinite order. I thought they might be isomorphic.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One is cyclic, the other is not.

Comment: @Joanpemo why is $\Bbb Q$ not cyclic tho?

Comment: For example, because for any $\;\frac ab\in\Bbb Q\;$ , all the elements in the cyclic group $\;\left\langle\frac ab\right\rangle\;$ have a finite number of prime factors in their denominators

Comment: @Joanpemo I still do not understand. why all the elements in the cyclic groups have finite number of prime numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $r$ is any element of $\mathbb{Q}$, there is an $x$ such that $x+x=r$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Also, I do not know why Q is not cyclic

Comment: Let $\varphi$ be an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $\varphi(r)=1$. Then there exists a rational $x$ \such that $x+x=r$. It follows that $\varphi(r)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(x)=1$. But there is no integer $y$ such that $y+y=1$.

Comment: As to why is $\mathbb{Q}$ not cyclic, suppose it is, and let $r$ be a generator. Verify that $r/2$ is not in the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $r$.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the ideas I used in the hint are basically the same as the ones used to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not cyclic.